# How to receive log in Log2console Log Viewer from Database table

Tags: logging, nlog, log-viewer

I think question is self explanatory. Again Log2Console use only File, UDP, WinDebug, MSMQ  EventLog ,TCP IP v4 and v6, Silverlight Socket Policy as Receiver.

Is there any way to configure it with database? I have logger database, log is stored in database, So i need a way to view those log in Log2Console Log Viewer.

If their any alternative solution, I would love it.

any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to alter the configuration of the logger that stores the messages to the database to also send them to any accepted Log2Console receivers (file, TCP, UDP, etc).

Another solution would be to write a small program that monitors the database and sends any new records to Log2Console as TCP or UDP for minimal overhead.